# What do gunslingers do with their hands?

Tags: single-word-requests

In movies and games with cowboys when they are in a duel their fingers are almost about to get their guns, but then their fingers just start wiggling.

[image]

IN this specific motion what are gunslingers doing with their hands, especially their fingers? Is there a specific word that describes this motion?

Comment: I think the term would be "wiggling their fingers to add visual interest for the audience".

Comment: (How many gunfights have you actually seen?  How would you know what they do with their fingers?)

Comment: @HotLicks It's something that's commonly used in plenty of old spaghetti western movies as well as games with cowboy-themed characters, like Overwatch, Mortal Kombat X, and Red Dead Redemption

Comment: They're limbering their fingers. Usually used with "up", but that's not needed for this case. That's what they're *doing*; the word for the *motion* might be something else again.

Comment: Like I said, it's to add interest to the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say the gunslinger had his...

> *fingers/hands [**twitching** over his guns](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fingers%20twitching%22#tbm=bks&q=%22twitching%20over%20his%20guns%22)* <sub>(+more results for singular [*gun*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22twitching%20over%20his%20gun%22))</sub>

**twitch** *- to move jerkily or spasmodically* [(thefreedictionary.com)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/twitching)

Comment: @cheers love Definitely twitching...where else would we get the phrase "twitchy trigger finger"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a formal term for this, but many seem to use ***hovering*** in situations like these.

For example:

> with his hands hovering only inches over his gun grips ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UY_AAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=gunslinger%20hovering%20hands&source=bl&ots=uhhHdIaJih&sig=r3Vo1zXuXONXfZsqc0MByka-Cw4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwini_GypKHNAhVGJCYKHde7CT8Q6AEIVDAM#v=onepage&q=gunslinger%20hovering%20hands&f=false))

and:

> Duke takes his stance, hand hovering over the Colt ([here](http://www.simplyscripts.com/scripts/NewYorkCityCowboysFinalDraft.pdf))

and:

> Their hands hover over their holsters. ([here](http://www.simplyscripts.com/scripts/NewYorkCityCowboysFinalDraft.pdf))

and:

> She flexed her fingers, an old-style gunslinger hovering her hand over her holster ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jlo8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT97&lpg=PT97&dq=gunslinger%20hovering%20hands&source=bl&ots=M_COU_4wQV&sig=EefgCMUKDt-EArtTivFxPEBdS38&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwini_GypKHNAhVGJCYKHde7CT8Q6AEIXTAO#v=onepage&q=gunslinger%20hovering%20hands&f=false))

and specifically in reference to a video game:

> keep your hand hovering over your holster ([here](https://support.ubi.com/en-US/Faqs/000017388/How-Do-I-Duel-in-Call-of-Juarez-Gunslinger))

*Hover*, of course, doesn't capture the finger wiggle. But the finger wiggle might be so ingrained in the public consciousness that just using *hover* will suggest it to those familiar with the imagery.

I was also thinking ***fingering*** might work, but it suggests actually touching the gun and it is often used in conjunction with *nervously*, as in "He was nervously fingering the gun in his holster".

Another option is ***flutter***, which has the same benefits as *hover*, while also suggesting movement.

A final option is to describe the fingers as ***undulating*** **over the holstered gun**, where *undulating* means "move with a smooth wavelike motion" (Google).

Comment: I'm mostly interested in the finger wiggle if that has a formal word for it. But thank you, hovering makes more sense for the hand